# retrieve data out of a public structure and collection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, collections

I'm using a collection and structure to store some parsed data in a class, but when i try to retrieve the data it is null. On form1 i'm i can get the response string which is all the raw data.  Am I adding the parsed data to the collection correctly?  Did I call it on form1 correctly?

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim dloader as new Downloader(blah)
 'this does not work
    Dim test as new _ListInfo
      msgbox(test.Name) ' produces an empty message box
'this works
     msgbox(dloader.Download)
End Sub
```

Here is my code for the class:

```
Public Structure _Info
  Dim Name As String
End Structure

Public Class Downloader
  Dim _ListCollection As New Collection(Of _ListInfo)

Public ReadOnly Property ListCollection() As Collection(Of _ListInfo)
    Get
        ListCollection = _ListCollection
    End Get
End Property

Public Function Download() As String
  'doing the download
  ParseList()
  Return _ResponseString
End Function    

Private Sub ParseList()
    _ListCollection.Clear()
 Dim Name As String
 Dim MyInfo As _ListInfo
   MyInfo.Name = Name
    _ListCollection.Add(MyInfo)
End Sub
```

Comment: The property is not set to anything, so it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect it to work? You are just newing-up a structure and accessing a property. Don't you want to do something like:

```
Dim dloader as new Downloader(blah)
dloader.Download()
' Show first name.
MsgBox(dloader.ListCollection(0).Name)
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  I know see where my thoughts were completely incorrect.  Thanks.